# PHP SDK v.3.1.1 - 'An active access token must be used' on simple example

Tags: facebook, sdk, facebook-php-sdk

I've had some big bugs implementing the latest PHP SDK and OAuth2, so I've broken it down into using the supplied example to demonstrate the problem I am experiencing.

I am using this code. I get the OAuthException 'An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.' When I click the Log In With Facebook link, I continue to get this error and I am not connected. Note that this does usually work when all cookies and sessions have been cleared, but after a couple of hours if I return it no longer works.

I'd be grateful for any help with this.

Also note this is not on a canvas page.

```
<?php
ob_start();
/**
 * Copyright 2011 Facebook, Inc.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may
 * not use this file except in compliance with the License. You may obtain
 * a copy of the License at
 *
 *     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT
 * WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the
 * License for the specific language governing permissions and limitations
 * under the License.
 */

require_once('../facebook-php-sdk/facebook.php');

include('app3.conf.inc.php');

$facebook = new Facebook(array (
            'appId' => $appConf['appID'],
            'secret' => $appConf['appsecret'],
        ));

// Get User ID
$user = $facebook->getUser();

// We may or may not have this data based on whether the user is logged in.
//
// If we have a $user id here, it means we know the user is logged into
// Facebook, but we don't know if the access token is valid. An access
// token is invalid if the user logged out of Facebook.
if ($user) {
  try {
    // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me?fields=permissions');
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
     error_log($e);
    $user = null;
  }
}


// Login or logout url will be needed depending on current user state.
if ($user) {
  $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
} else {
  $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
}

// This call will always work since we are fetching public data.
try
{
    $naitik = $facebook->api('/naitik');
}
catch (Exception $ex)
{
    echo("Exception with api/naitik:\n<pre>");
    var_dump($ex);
    echo("</pre>");
    die();
}

?>
<!doctype html>
<html xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
  <head>
    <title>php-sdk</title>
    <style>
      body {
        font-family: 'Lucida Grande', Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
      }
      h1 a {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #3b5998;
      }
      h1 a:hover {
        text-decoration: underline;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>php-sdk</h1>

    <?php if ($user): ?>
      <a href="<?php echo $logoutUrl; ?>">Logout</a>
    <?php else: ?>
      <div>
        Login using OAuth 2.0 handled by the PHP SDK:
        <a href="<?php echo $loginUrl; ?>">Login with Facebook</a>
      </div>
    <?php endif ?>

    <h3>PHP Session</h3>
    <pre><?php print_r($_SESSION); ?></pre>

    <h3>Cookies</h3>
    <pre><?php print_r($_COOKIE); ?></pre>


    <?php if ($user): ?>
      <h3>You</h3>
      <img src="https://graph.facebook.com/<?php echo $user; ?>/picture">

      <h3>Your User Object (/me)</h3>
      <pre><?php print_r($user_profile); ?></pre>
    <?php else: ?>
      <strong><em>You are not Connected.</em></strong>
    <?php endif ?>

    <h3>Public profile of Naitik</h3>
    <img src="https://graph.facebook.com/naitik/picture">
    <?php echo $naitik['name']; ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: There is a signed_request in the cookies. When I decode it, it is about 6 hours old.

Comment: Do you have a code in your url? You need to use code to get an access_token.

Comment: Yes, after clicking the Login With Facebook link, I have a code in the URL.

Comment: I started dumping every API call made by the SDK.

The first one is to https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token and it results in string '{"error":{"message":"Code was invalid or expired. Session has expired at unix time 1317819600. The current unix time is 1317836099.","type":"OAuthException"}}' (length=158)  It is using the same old code, not the code in the URL. Seems it is getting stored somewhere like a cookie or session.

Comment: Seems there was a cookie named 'fbsr_{appid}' (real app ID in there) which contained a signed request, which in turn contained a 'code.' The SDK was using this instead of the latest code given in the URL. I seemed to have fixed it by adding unset($_COOKIE['fbsr_' . $this->getAppId()]); to clearAllPersistentData, and calling this if a code was given. I am not confident about this SDK now.

Answer (score 2):

A bug has been raised and accepted by Facebook for the latest SDK. I suggest downgrading to one from earlier in 2011 until then. It solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you were close. Below the php config for facebook, I provide a if GET query to detect if user logged out. When they log out, the code inside the condition fires

`unset($_COOKIE['fbsr_' . $config['appId']]);`

instead of

`unset($_COOKIE['fbsr_' . $this->getAppId()]);`

This seemed to workout like a charm.

Comment: Here is what I was able to do to overcome the issue: 
if(isset($_GET['logoff'])){ 
 // Initialize the session.
 session_start(); 
 // Unset all of the session variables.
 $_SESSION = array(); 
 // If it's desired to kill the session, also delete the session cookie.
 if (ini_get("session.use_cookies")) {
  $params = session_get_cookie_params();
  setcookie(session_name(), '', time() - 42000,
   $params["path"], $params["domain"],
   $params["secure"], $params["httponly"]
  );
 } 
 // Finally, destroy the session.
 session_destroy();
}else{
 // Get User ID
 $user = $facebook->getUser();  
}

Comment: I think you also need to destroy the fbsr_appid cookie. I downgraded to an older version and haven't had a problem. A bug has been accepted by FB.